# How can Snape talk to him after he is dead?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Deathly Hallows* part 2, Harry is looking into Snape's memories and he sees Snape talking to

> Dumbledore asking him about Harry,

and Snape sends his Patronus to go help Harry find the sword of Gryffindor (*Deathly Hallows* Part 1). How is Snape talking to

> Dumbledore, because this conversation takes place after Dumbledore was killed?

Answer (score 15):

Snape was talking to Dumbledore's headmaster portrait, at least in the book:

> ‘Headmaster! They are camping in the Forest of Dean! The Mudblood –’
>
> ‘Do not use that word!’
>
> ‘– the Granger girl, then, mentioned the place as she opened her bag
> and I heard her!’
>
> ‘Good. Very good!’ cried the portrait of Dumbledore behind the
> Headmaster’s chair. ‘Now, Severus, the sword! Do not forget that it
> must be taken under conditions of need and valour – and he must not
> know that you give it! If Voldemort should read Harry’s mind and see
> you acting for him –’
>
> ‘I know,’ said Snape curtly. He approached the portrait of Dumbledore
> and pulled at its side. It swung forwards, revealing a hidden cavity
> behind it, from which he took the sword of Gryffindor. *Deathly Hallows*